# How To Unit Test React Router Routes declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm trying to unit test a React component which generate my app's Routes declaration for `react-router-dom`.

My code look like this:

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loading from 'app/components/Loading';

export interface IRoute {
    exact?: boolean;
    path?: string;
    component?: any;
    routes?: IRoute[];
}

export const renderRoutes = (routes: IRoute[] = []): JSX.Element => (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <Switch>
            {routes.map((route: IRoute, i) => {
                const Component = route.component;

                return (
                    <Route
                        key={i}
                        path={route.path}
                        exact={route.exact}
                        render={(props) => <>{route.routes ? renderRoutes(route.routes) : <Component {...props} />}</>}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </Switch>
    </Suspense>
);

const routes: IRoute[] = [
    {
        exact: true,
        path: '/404',
        component: lazy(() => import('./app/errors/NotFound')),
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        routes: [
            {
                exact: true,
                path: '/home',
                component: lazy(() => import('./app/home/Home')),
            },
            {
                component: () => <Redirect to="/404" />,
            },
        ],
    },
];

export default routes;
```

And my attempt to test it, which fail, look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes, { renderRoutes, IRoute } from './routes';

describe('Routes declaration', () => {
    it('Render Routes', () => {
        const routesComponent = renderRoutes(routes);

        assertsRoutes(routes, routesComponent);
    });
});

const assertsRoutes = (routes: IRoute[], routesComponent: JSX.Element) => {
    routes.forEach((route, i) => {
        if (route.routes) {
            assertsRoutes(route.routes, routesComponent);
        }

        const Component = route.component;
        expect(routesComponent).toContain(<Route key={i} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} render={(props) => <>{<Component {...props} />}</>} />);
    });
};
```

How can I test that `renderRoutes` properly generate Route components for all given `IRoute`?